# Watching you working hard made my eyes water

Tags: sentence-structure

Are these sentence structures correct and idiomatic?

1.It is nice to see you show up on time at work.

2.It is nice to see you showing up on time at work.

3.What a surprise to see you show up/showing up on time at work.

4.Watching/seeing you work/working hard made my eyes water, son.I believe you are going to pass the exam.

Comment: 4 seems grammatically OK, but I ma not sure what you are trying to say. Nobody's eyes ever watered watching me work...

Comment: @user3169 Actually I used it in sarcastic way for a lazy boy. btw "work" and "working" fit here for sentence 4?

Comment: FWIW:  When I read _Made my eyes water_ I thought someone's job was chopping lots of onions.  If you mean father was _tearing up_  out of pride, _brought tears to my eyes_ would be more common way to express it.  _Eyes watering_ is used for non-emotional release of water through the tear ducts - usually due to an irritant or a sharp blow.

Comment: @Adam thank you for the feedback.It is very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are possible with the exception of *... made my eyes watered ...*. We make/made/will make someone/something **do** (bare infinitive) something.

Incidentally, 'water', the correct form, needs to be followed by a comma; 'son' is used as a vocative.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.So what is the difference between sentence 1 and sentence 2 can I ask?

Comment: Nice to see you back! :-) Been missed ...

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what @user3169 said, your last phrase:

> Watching/seeing you work/working hard made my eyes water, son.I believe you are going to pass the exam.

Is
(a) Two sentences.
(b) Missing a space
Should be:

> Watchng/seeing you work/working hard made my eyes water, son*. I* believe you are going to pass the *(or that)* exam.